# gdaltools exports geojson point as multipoint

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, ogr

I have some python code that uses gdaltools python module to convert a geojson file to postgis.

```
ogr = gdaltools.ogr2ogr()
ogr.set_encoding("UTF-8")
print("Setting Input")
ogr.set_input(file_name, srs="EPSG:4326")

gdaltools.Wrapper.BASEPATH = os.environ['GDAL_PATH']

print("Setting Conn")
conn = gdaltools.PgConnectionString(host=os.environ['DB_HOST'],
                                    port=os.environ['DB_PORT'],
                                    dbname=os.environ['DB_NAME'],
                                    user=os.environ['DB_USERNAME'],
                                    password=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
                                    schema=str(self.table_prefix) + "_" + str(code))

print("Setting Output")
ogr.set_output(conn, table_name=table, srs="EPSG:27700")
print("OGR Execute")
ogr.execute()
```

The GeoJSON contains a geometry of type point

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -1.0600739160455448,
        51.53592123798526
    ]
}
```

What I'm seeing when exporting the data from the database, is that it appears to be converted from type Point in the geojson to type Multipoint in the database.

When loading the geometry from one table into another table - with no transformation - I get the following error:

```
Geometry type (MultiPoint) does not match column type (Point)
```

Any Ideas as to where why ogr2ogr would be casting to Multipoint from Point?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [option](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) `-nlt POINT`

Doing so forces the output data type to be of the `POINT` type, and not `MULTIPOINT` as you are currently getting.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @JGH for the point towards the answer.

Actually the module has a way of handling this that wasn't obvious, In pygdaltools module, any geometry that is going to PostgreSQL or Postgis is automatically set to MULTIPOINT. To override this, add the following piece of code
`ogr.geom_type = 'POINT'`